# Jquery ajax json data is not handled correctly by IE(6~9) :(

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I would be thankful for any help!

I'm using the following code to create areas with "random" products.
The JSON data received from php-script is like this:

```
{"New":[{"product_id":"50",...},...],
"Best":[{"product_id":"26",...},...],
...}
```

"New" products must go to `<div id="New">`, and so on.

Problem 1: Although it works fine with all fine browsers, 
IE(6~9) leaves all divs empty.

Problem 2: I would like to have this ajax-JSON data to be cached by the client.
As can be seen in FireBug, these requests are not cached. Do I have to resort to plug-ins?

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/index.php?AjaxRequest&action=5",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
    var new_str ='<ul>';
    $(value.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()}).slice(0,3)).each(function(){
    new_str+='<li><a href="#" class="right_sidebar" onclick="location.href=\''+this.link+'\'">';
    new_str+= '<img class="right_sidebar_thumb" src="'+this.image+'" alt="'+this.name+'"/></a></li>';
    });
    new_str+='</ul>';
        $('#'+key).append(new_str);
    });
    }});
```

Comment: Setting JavaScript onclick events from JavaScript with jQuery?  Seriously?

Comment: No duplicate IDs for sure. And about onclick events, just need it to work, when it works I will see to the details. Thanks!

Comment: Why the hell do you use onclick where a plain href would to the job?

Comment: @Adam: Yeah it's ugly. But since he's building a HTML string (hopefully to keep the number of DOM modifications low as they are slow as hell) the only better solution would be using delegates (which he should use in that case).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. href will do the job. But the problem here is different. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Thief - You are totally incorrect, I'm sorry to say.  `$('<a href="#">').click(function () { ... });`  You can construct elements without appending them to the DOM right away.  You construct a container node, append to it (which is cheap) and then append that container into the document.  The performance of this approach is fast.  What you want to avoid is consecutive appends into the large document DOM.

Comment: @Adam: When appending them at some point he'll need to append all of them - which will be slow since it'll have to be done with multiple appends.

Comment: @Thief - I'm sorry, that's not accurate.  Here's the word from the founder of jQuery, John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/  Notice his approach: append to a document fragment, then append the document fragment to the DOM.  It appends everything at once, and only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem but when I work with JSON I very often have problems with the structure of my JSON. To help find the problem I use an online JSON validator which I find very good: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check that the last item in the JSON object does not have a comma after it. I know this can break IE as it can't handle there being an empty item

Answer (score 0):

Jquery expects there to be only one element with a given id. Try switching to

```
<div class=’new-product’/>
```

and match with

```
$('.new-product')
```

as for catching, try using the error method

```
$.ajax({
  error: function(){
  }
});
```

Comment: I have several divs with unique ids. changing from ids to classes changes nothing, and there are no errors...but anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution!
It turns out IE was caching jquery requests.
Adding `cache: false` resolved the problem.
Down with IE!